# TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

When I run my controller file I got this Error.

```
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined**

 if (attribute.attributeId == 'created_on_attr' || attribute.attributeId == 'modified_on_attr' || 
      attribute.attributeId == 'created_by_attr' || attribute.attributeId == 'modified_by_attr' ){
           alert(attribute.attributeId.indexOf("fileUpload")!= -1);
           attribute.isEnabled = false;
 }
```

Can you provide solution for this

Comment: Can you provide code for this?

Comment: alert your 'attribute' JSON. You will find attribute.attributeId undefined.

Comment: Use === and not ==, that should solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've posted, it appears that the property "attributeId" is not defined for "attribute". You should probably have a look at the attribute variable and make sure that it has all of the properties you expect.

If, on the other hand, attributeId is an optional property, and you are trying to test BOTH whether it exists and if it contains "fileUpload" then you probably want something like:

`attribute.attributeId && attribute.attributeId.indexOf("fileUpload")!= -1`

**EDIT** After I posted, you updated your question, however the general gist of what I am saying still applies: none of the conditions in your if statement are checking to see if the attributeId field actually exists on your object. So, either your variable is set incorrectly, or you just need to add more gate-keeping code.